# Issue consuming Webservice that has restricted complex type through .net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

Issue description :

We are trying to consume a service that is exposed by TIBCO in SOAP format, we are facing issues during transforming a restricted complex type object it into .net object.  We are able to receive the SOAP packet, but its failing to deserialize it into the valid c# object.  However the object was instantiated but without any value (values were null). The response status is success, but the translation of the object is failing. Below is the WSDL snippet for the reference. Apart from building a custom deserialzer is there any other better approach for this problem :

```
<xs:complexType name="GetIndividualByCIMIdResponseType">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                This response 
            </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="cst:SimpleResponse">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Individual" type="ns0:IndividualRestrictedType" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
          <xs:complexType name="IndividualRestrictedType">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:restriction base="ns0:IndividualType">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="DoNotMerge" type="ns0:DoNotMergeType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="PartyIdentifier" type="ns0:CIMIdentifierType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="EmailAccountList" type="ns0:EmailAccountListType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="TelephoneServiceList" type="ns0:TelephoneServiceListType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="AddressList" type="ns0:AddressListType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="DateOfBirth" type="ns0:DateOfBirthType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="FamilyName" type="ns0:FamiltyNameType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="ns0:FirstNameType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="Initials" type="ns0:InitialsType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="MiddleNames" type="ns0:MiddleNamesType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="PreferredName" type="ns0:PreferredNameType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:el`enter code here`ement name="Sex" type="ns0:SexType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="Title" type="ns0:TitleType" minOccurs="0"/>
                            <xs:element name="YearOfBirth" type="ns0:YearOfBirthType" minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
```